# (sharp) # sign in query string and SEO

Tags: ajax, seo

I have a site Index.html and there is a categories menu generated from database. Menu consists of HTML anchors, but href attribute is always something like "Index.html#cat=xyz" because content of each category is generated through AJAX call.

```
<a href="Index.html#cat=1" onclick="javascript:LoadHref("cat","1");"></a><br />
<a href="Index.html#cat=2" onclick="javascript:LoadHref("cat","2");"></a><br />
<a href="Index.html#cat=3" onclick="javascript:LoadHref("cat","3");"></a><br />
```

From the AJAX side everything works, but I want to ask if for example Google or other search engine will index these links which contains # (sharp) sign. Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking the wrong question.  If you want your links to be indexed, make them obvious to a crawler about the content.  Multiple links to the same page won't help your SEO efforts.  Consider creating a separate page for "contacts" "investor information" "careers" (or whatever your categories are) and publishing them.  Then your link becomes

```
<a href="careers.html">careers</a>
```

etc.  When a human sees this link (your actual end target) he'll be able to make a better choice whether or not it's the "right" result.

Answer (score 1):

using it like that will not work good for search engins and for users not have javascript enabled.

you need to make it lie facebook url redirect with seo friendly

you will need to use jQuery Hash url

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax and when the user click on the link use the attribute - `onclick="LoadHref('cat','1');return false;"`